# Symbols in megabus and national express

Tags: uk, buses, megabus

Can some one tell me what does the symbols in megabus and national express booking [site](https://www.checkmybus.co.uk/#departureDate=2019-07-03&origin=London%2C%20United%20Kingdom%2451.5073509%2C-0.1277583&destination=Edinburgh%2C%20United%20Kingdom%2455.953252%2C-3.188267&sortValue=Price&sortOrder=ascending&radius=15&adults=1&returnDate=2019-07-16).

I see one Wifi  symbol, mobile charger symbol (I guess).

I do not understand other symbols. Can some one tell what the symbols mean?

Comment: Please include a screen shot of the symbols you're asking about.

Comment: @DavidRicherby something is wrong with my computer. So, could not take screenshots. I could have added otherwise :) :) my question is answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hover my mouse pointer over the symbol I get a tip pop up.

The ones I see are:

- wifi on board
- toilets
- electric sockets
- compartments for hand luggage (presumably overhead shelf inside coach)
- luggage transportation (presumably a luggage hold below the floor of the coach)
- drinks
- snacks

If you look at individual operators' pages you will see a further description of amenities under 'service and comfort'

eg

https://www.checkmybus.co.uk/bus-providers/citylink#ser

[image: Screen shot of booking]

Comment: I am not able to see pop up :O

Comment: Try a different browser. Make sure the browser allows "pop-ups." Try less aggressive security settings in your computer OS.

Comment: Yes, I am able to see now.. Thanks..